# Nested lapply taken longer than nested for loops

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I am computing  scores from data in dataFrame_1  and populating a 400M cells dataFrame_2 using nested for loops.
To test my code and the job I created simulated data, where:

(cellxcl_df) surrogates dataFrame_1
(cellxcell_df) surrogates DataFrame_2

As you can see from my code below, nested for loop take 1.8 min to be populated with data (1M cells in the cellxcell_df.) If linear, when  applying it to the real data I will have to wait 12 h before my next interaction with the data.

Since I read to many time that lapply is much faster than for loops I tried a nested lapply code. However for my surprise I had to kill the process since it was already taken > 10 times the time of the original for loop. I am doing something wrong with my nested lapply loop or nested lapply are not so efficient in time neither?

````
###create toy dataframes to try the code
```{r}

nm <- c(paste("c", (1:1000), sep=""))

cellxcell_df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=1000, nrow=1000))
colnames(cellxcell_df) <- nm
rownames(cellxcell_df) <- nm

cellxcl_val <- sample(1:10,10000, replace = TRUE)
cellxcl_df <-data.frame(matrix(cellxcl_val,ncol=1000, nrow=10))
colnames(cellxcl_df) <- nm
```
#####This is the code with for loop
```{r}
start.time <- Sys.time()

for (i in rownames(cellxcell_df)) {
    for (j in colnames(cellxcell_df)) { 
    cellxcell_df[i,j] <- sum(cellxcl_df[, i] == cellxcl_df[, j])
  }
}

end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
```
````

Below is my attempt to replace nested for loops with nested lapply loops

````
```{r}
start.time <- Sys.time()

lapply(as.list(rownames(cellxcell_df)), function(i){
        lapply(as.list(rownames(cellxcell_df)), function(j){
         cellxcell_df[i,j] <- sum(cellxcl_df[, i] == cellxcl_df[, j])             })
})

end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
```
````

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The logic of your code is unclear. You are cycling through rows and then using the row name to index a column. If the row names didn't happen to match the column names, the code wouldn't even work.

Comment: Why do you use row names?  This is a rather slow and using O(n) lookup time.  Cannot you just use row (and column) indices?

Comment: I am not sure at all that lapply is fast.  Haven't done much timings, but [here](https://info201.github.io/control-structures.html#loops) I found lapply is 8x slower for quick loops.  In general, lapply is just a beefed up R loop, not anything done at C level like true vectorized functions.

Comment: Dear Edward: cellxcl_df have 10 rows. Each r is a experiment that assign a class (numbers from 1 to 10) to each of the 1000 variables (c1 to c1000).  The cellbycell_df  is populated with scores indicating how many time a pair of variables where in the same category considering the 10 experiment. E.g if  c1-c2 cell get a score of 10 means than in each row of cellxcl_df c1 and c2 get identical value. Hope this clarify